# Missing Menu Assignment in Joomla Module Custom HTML

Tags: joomla, module, joomla3.0

Recently we noticed that our module assignment tab is missing and we cannot assign any items to some modules, example: prntscr.com/8obd8u

Here is snapshot from our previous website (to compare with the current one): prntscr.com/8obdep

Does anyone have any idea what we should check? We disabled all the plugins / one by one to check if it's going to help us, still nothing.

Also, all the pages have a Custom HTML modue. See : prntscr.com/8od9rw

So everything on the page above with a Custom HTML module doesn't have that "Module Assignment"...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using web inspector on the problem pages to check the HTML? Maybe the missing tabs are there but there's conflicting CSS from some source which is hiding the tab list items.

You could also try changing the admin template to Hathor and see if that changes anything ... wouldn't solve the problem but might provide some clues.

Good luck!